# how to achieve pass TType value by the MyEvents function

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-3.0

Here in this code showing one error at MyEvents. What happen there. and how to achieve pass TType value by the MyEvents function

```
public class MListBox : ListBox
{
    public Type TType { get; set; }

     public void LoadList()
    {
        MyEvents<TType , TType >.LoadList("getList").ForEach(w => this.Items.Add(w));
    }
}

public void main(string[] args)
{
  MListBox mb= new MListBox();
  mb.TType = typeof(STOCK);
  mb.LoadList();
}


 public static class MyEvents<T,M> where T : class where M : class
{
    public static M m;
    public static T t;
    public static List<objectCollection> LoadList(string _method)
    {
        m = Activator.CreateInstance<M>();
        MethodInfo method = typeof(M).GetMethod(_method);
        List<objectCollection> ret = (List<objectCollection>)method.Invoke(m, null);
        return ret;
    }
}

public class STOCK()
{
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: It always helps to give the error.

Comment: Thank u, but how can i pass t-class in my custom listbox

Comment: `T` is not a variable.

Comment: i dont see any error in the code, u can use it like this `MListBox<YourClass> a = new MListBox<YourClass>();` so template variable T will be YourClass in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are diving into world of generics. Using a generic type parameter T you can write a single class that other client code can use without incurring the cost or risk of runtime casts or boxing operations.

A generic class, such as `MListBox<T>` cannot be used as-is because it is not really a type. so to use `MListBox<T>`, you must declare and instantiate a constructed type by specifying a type argument inside the angle brackets.

eg

```
MListBox<YourClass> a = new MListBox<YourClass>();
```

where YourClass is type parameter you intend to pass in

more info on generics

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx

**Update**

```
    public class MListBox<T, M> : ListBox
        where T : class
        where M : class, new()
    {
        public void LoadList()
        {
            MyEvents<T, M>.LoadList("getList").ForEach(w => this.Items.Add(w));
        }
    }

    public void main(string[] args)
    {
        MListBox<object,STOCK> mb = new MListBox<object,STOCK>();
        mb.LoadList();
    }


    public static class MyEvents<T, M>
        where T : class
        where M : class, new()
    {
        public static M m;
        public static T t;
        public static List<T> LoadList(string _method)
        {
            m = new M();
            MethodInfo method = typeof(M).GetMethod(_method);
            List<T> ret = (List<T>)method.Invoke(m, null);
            return ret;
        }
    }
```

wrapper class to be used in xaml

```
class StockListBox : MListBox<object,STOCK>
{
}
```

use in xaml as, where local is your namesapce

```
<local:StockListBox />
```

Comment: Thank you... And i have to put this control in xaml. but it's showing like <MListBox'1> and getting error in xaml code...

Comment: you can create a wrapper `class StockListBox : MListBox<object,STOCK>` and use that class in xaml, as xaml does not support generic class declaration unless you are using xaml 2009. if you are using xaml 2009 then you can use like this `<MListBox x:TypeArguments="x:object,l:STOCK"/>`

Comment: xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winf/2006/xaml"xmlns:mlist="clr-namespace:SMS.Design.Interface"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"><Grid>
        <mlist:MListBox x:TypeArguements="x:object,1:object"></mlist:MListBox></Grid>

Comment: I'm using this code in my xaml Listbox but x:TypeArguements is getting error. i'm using 2010 visual studio

Comment: check the xaml workspace which you are using, it is `xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"` then you may not use x:TypeArguements at element level, you may need to change to xaml 2009(if available) or use the wrapper class method.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me how to change xaml 2006 to xaml 2009

Comment: typically xaml 2009 is available with framework 4 but only for loose xaml's so if you are building a desktop application using vs2010 and blend then you may not use 2009. if you have separate xaml file and load them via xamlrader it will work. so I would suggest you to go for wrapper class method as it will be compiled in vs2010 too.

Comment: Thank you again. please give me any link to create a wrapper class method....

Comment: added example in answer